# Is there a linear or logarhythmic relationship between scale and electromagnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

Are there any instances where electromagnetic force from a point source doesn't follow the inverse square law?

Comment: there is no magnetic point source and a carge as electric point source follows always the inverse square law. so what do you think of as "the point source"!

Comment: Why do you think Coulomb’s Law might have exceptions? If it did, it wouldn’t be a law.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal point dipole, quadrupole, etc. follow inverse cube, quad, etc. laws.

These are physical idealizations since a point dipole involves putting two charges infinitesimally close together while letting the magnitude of each charge go to $\infty$ so as to keep the dipole moment constant. A discussion of ideal vs. physical dipoles is given in Griffiths's *Introduction to Electromagnetism*.

So, I think it depends on what you mean by point source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is indeed, but not in a 3-dimensional space. If the space dimension is arbitrary, let's call it $d$, then the electromagnetic field of a point charge scales like

$$\left|\vec E\right|(r) \sim \frac{1}{r^{d-1}}$$